# Combine many files to a single file INDIVIDUALLY

Tags: bash

In my directory, I have the following: One constant file (a.txt) & Many other other files (1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt...etc)

I want to combine a.txt with 1.txt into one file called a_1.txt, I want to combine a.txt with 2.txt into one file called a_2.txt, I want to combine a.txt with 3.txt into one file called a_3.txt,
and so on.

I've tried using the find command as so:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -execdir cat a.txt {} > receptor_{} \;
```

but does not work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

With bash:

```
for i in [0-9]*.txt; do cat a.txt "$i" >"a_$i"; done
```

Comment: thank you! Would you know how to use the find command to solve this?

Comment: I suggest: `find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '[0-9]*.txt' -printf "cat a.txt %f >a_%f\n" | sh` `%f` is file name without path.